# Python MemoryError on struct.unpack

Tags: python, memory, unpack

I'm getting a `MemoryError` when trying to unpack data that I read from a file. I want to be able to read every single byte that's why I'm unpacking it. When I unpack just 1 byte it works but when i want to read the whole dump (`total_size`) it gives the error. I have no idea what to do.

```
def read_memory(self, mem_file, address, byte_count):
        mem_file.seek(address)
        data = mem_file.read(byte_count)
        return data

memory_dump = self.read_memory(mem_file, start_addr, total_size)
unpacked = struct.unpack("{}B".format(total_size), memory_dump) # MemoryError
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: why are you unpacking `data`? if `data` is a bytestring (likely) then it is already a byte sequence. How do you use `unpacked` later? If you need an object that looks  like  as if  you read the whole file, you could try `mmap` (even if the file doesn't fit in memory as long as it fits in the address space).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I want to compare each byte to element in a bytearray. but memory_dump[0] for example is '\x7f' and I cant compare that to a byte. How would i do that?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it using hexlify. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: you could use `mmap`, `array.array.fromfile`, `bytearray(bytestring)` or in reverse `bytes(some_bytearray)` depending on a particular case. There could be several efficient ways (indexing `str` on Python 2 returns a single length `str`, it returns `int` on Python 3). `hexlify()` that returns *text* representation of bytes is not it. It might be an interesting separate question: are you comparing binary files? How big they are? Is there a larger than byte internal structure? Is it necessary to read the whole file at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I didn't have enough RAM

Comment: I have the same problem. I need to read binary data of 128MB, where a pixel is represented in 16bits. Then, I cast to float64 numpy array. According to my computes, I only need 524MB of RAM. My PC has 8GB RAM (about 4GB RAM free on working).
I don´t know whats happening, maybe I have a problem in numpy reading, or I need to read as slices in the image....